# Telepot MessageLoop: How to stop run_as_thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, telegram, telepot

checking incoming messages from Telegram works pretty well with

```
MessageLoop(bot, handle).run_as_thread()
```

But how can stop this thread from running? I tried join(), but with no success!

Answer (score 0):

I used stopit=False at the top of the program
Then global stopit in def Handle
if you receive your stop command stopit=True
After the MessageLoop if have a non stopping while and in that I do
if stopit == True:
sys.exit()